# Model editor, Open existing model

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use Gazebo 7.11 with ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am making some custom models using the Model Editor. How do I open an existing model to make further changes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18990/model-editor,-open-existing-model/) by [robotlab](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4963/robotlab/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As @raskkii's answer describes, you can insert it directly on the editor, but as @robotlab points out in their comment, the model is inserted as a "nested model" and is not editable.

Try this instead:

1. Open Gazebo
2. Before entering the model editor, insert the model from the insert menu
3. Right-click the model and choose `Edit in Model Editor`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotlab](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4963/robotlab/) on 2018-04-14**:
Thanks for the suggestion, maybe this is the best or only way to do it, though I then experience an issue. If I insert my model into my world and right-click and select Edit, then it will open the model as-is. This is not a problem for static models, which are not affected by collision or gravity, however the has experience some changes in the world, then the new pose will be transferred to the Model Editor as well. Do you know a way to avoid this?

**Comment by [robotlab](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4963/robotlab/) on 2018-04-14**:
There is really no way to open the model directly in the Model Editor, would be very nice?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-04-15**:
Yes, I agree it would be a nice feature to have, feel free to ticket a suggestion here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-04-15**:
As for the model changing position due to gravity, how about pausing the simulation before inserting it?

**Comment by [robotlab](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4963/robotlab/) on 2018-04-15**:
Sure, that may be the solution. I will ticket the suggestion. Thanks a lot for your swift help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Launch Gazebo, press Ctrl+M to launch Model Editor. Find your existing custom model from the dropdown list on the left, place it in the world. Do the modifications you'd like. Save.

Note: I think it saves it as a new model file so it doesn't overwrite unless you have it save with the same name.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotlab](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4963/robotlab/) on 2018-04-13**:
My model consists of several parts or Links. If I do that, it will insert it as one part/assembly, similar as you would e.g. insert a subassembly into a new assembly in SolidWorks. It does not let me edit the properties and Joints between each individual part.

**Comment by [Abraham](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8542/abraham/) on 2019-03-22**:
OK I see I can open from drop down list but it always asks position to place the model I want to place the permanently fixed to the  position how can I do that ?